Why permission must be 777 to write from a perl script outside cgi-bin?
Running AlmaLinux 8.
I need to run perl/cgi scripts outside the cgi-bin, I mean inside let's say a public_html/1/ directory.
I added the requested lines in .htaccess, pl scripts are 755, all is correct, scripts are executed.
But the script cannot write anything if the directory public_html/1/ isn't 777.
The log shows an "cannot write to closed filehandle..."
If I run the script from cgi-bin, it writes normally in public_html/1/ in 755.
Where am I wrong ?
Thank you !

Because that's the way that *nix operating systems work.

Sorry but on other box with Centos 7, no problem at all... Isn't there a way to change this?

on the other box with Centos 7, no problem - I'm having trouble with my Hyundai pulling to the right when I'm on the highway. In my other car, which is a Ford, no problem* makes as much sense as what you've written. Two different OSes, two different platforms. Maybe the other machine is configured differently, or your AlmaLinux app runs in a different user group that has different privileges in the folder, or maybe there's a difference in the app configuration between the two systems. Just because a different system works fine doesn't mean that the system you're on is identical.
